# Reg Expression Names with two caps without spaces for IQAndreas PHP Spam Filter

Tags: php, regex, spam, spam-prevention, chronoforms

I want to add an reg expression entry to one of the blacklist that will filter any person's names that has two capitals but without spaces because I see a lot of spammers with names like MarcelBoilt, RobertGef, ZichardMed, IngaOxina.

How should i write the Reg Expression to block these names? These one word names must have at least 3 letters.

Blacklist Requirement:
- Any regular expression syntax can be used here (without the delimiters).
- Regular expressions are always case insensitive.
- No regular expression may span more than one line.
- Anything after the '#' character until the end of a line is ignored, so use this for comments.
- If you only want to write out keywords, remember to escape special characters that have meaning in regex.

Reference:
https://github.com/IQAndreas/php-spam-filter

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve what you need?

Comment: I've tried 
\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b and [A-Z].*[A-Z]

Comment: Something about the syntax requirement that its not taking the normal regex syntax

Comment: The correct syntax look something like:
https?:\/\/[^\/]+\.pl\/\S+,s,\d{2,8}\/

Comment: This did not work: (?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2})

Comment: This did not work: ^[A-Z]{2}$

Comment: Your requirements say "Regular expressions are always case insensitive", so a rule based on the case does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```regex
^[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+
```

Comment: Here is the way I tested my answer. https://regex101.com/r/wZie2X/1 If it doesn't work for you, try customizing it and sharing a link to it so we get a better idea of what you need.

Comment: Thanks. It works in the tester. But for some reason my form now detect any word as spam.

Comment: How do I convert this into a input pattern? I tried pattern="/^((?!^[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+).)*$/ but didnt work.